# Event Handler Waiting for AJAX Call From Other Event Handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a jQuery handler for the change event of several text boxes.

```
$(vendorsPopUp).on('change', 'input', function (e) {
    // Call server to calculations new results
    $.post( ... );
    // Then update client elements with new results
}
```

I have another handler for when my Save button is clicked.

```
$('#VendorsPopUpSave', vendorsPopUp).on('click', function (e) {
    // Call server to save new results
    $.post( ... );
});
```

I have a problem if the user edits a text box and then clicks the Save button:

First my handler for the change event is called, and then my handler for the Save button is called. (*Note: The change event is not called until the text box loses focus, and this does not occur in this scenario until **after** the Save button is clicked.*) The problem is that, when the handler for the Save button is called, the AJAX call from the first handler has not yet finished.

Ideally, the Save button handler would wait until the AJAX call from the first handler has finished, and then proceed.

Is there an accepted practice for handling this type of scenario?

Comment: Disable the save button while waiting for a response to the change event's ajax. Would also be a good idea to show a spinner icon next to it or on it while waiting.

Comment: Not sure if it's necessarily an accepted practice - but you could always disable the save button when you call your change event, then enable it once the AJAX request completes

Comment: @KevinB: That wouldn't help. The Save button is what initiates the event. Disabling it then would be too late.

Comment: If you disable it, it would never be initiated before the change ajax has completed.

Comment: @entropic: I don't call the change event, the browser does. And since the Save button initiates the entire sequence, disabling it then would be too late.

Comment: I still don't understand why you can't disable the save button in your change event, then enable it when the change event AJAX completes..  what is preventing you from doing that?

Comment: @KevinB: One of us is missing something. The AJAX call doesn't even start in the scenario I described until after the Save button has been clicked. Are you saying disabling it after it's been clicked will affect it's behavior?

Comment: No, here's the process: The input is changed -> The save button is disabled -> Ajax request 1 is sent to the server to calculate new values -> Ajax request 1 completes and inserts new values into form -> Save button is enabled -> user clicks save button -> ajax request 2 is sent to server with form data.

Comment: @entropic: Nothing is preventing me from doing that, but I don't see how it helps. My first handler is called automatically by the browser *after* the Save button is clicked. How does it help to disable the Save button after it was clicked?

Comment: @JonathanWood what Kevin B said.  Are we missing something here?

Comment: @KevinB: I'm afraid that is not the process. The input is changed, but since the focus hasn't changed, the change event does not fire yet. Then the user clicks the save button. Then the browser calls the change event and then the click event. There is no chance to disable the Save button that I can see.

Comment: Now we're getting somewhere. A focus/blur event is not a change event, that's where the confusion is coming from. You can prevent the click of the save button in thsi case by simply preventing the default action on blur of the input.

Comment: Note, the action of clicking on the save button while being in the text input does this: blur on input. mousedown on button. mouseup on button, click on button. Therefore, if you prevent the event at the blur on input, it will never reach the button.

Comment: What confuses me is that you're using "change" in the code in your question, not blur. So where is this... loses focus coming in? simply typing in the input should be triggering that change event.

Comment: @KevinB: You can edit a text box all day long and it will not fire any change events. Only when a modified text box loses the focus will the change event occur.

Comment: No you're right, it doesn't trigger it. sorry! it's "input" that triggers that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can store the jqxhr object for the first request in a variable, then in your click handler check if that variable is set, and defer the 2nd ajax until the first request completes (jqxhr objects are promises)

```
var xhr;

$(vendorsPopUp).on('change', 'input', function (e) {
    // Call server to calculations new results
    xhr = $.post( ... );
    // Then update client elements with new results
}


$('#VendorsPopUpSave', vendorsPopUp).on('click', function (e) {
    // Call server to save new results
    var post = function(){
      $.post( ... );
    };

    if(xhr)
      xhr.then(post);

    // else post(); 
});
```

Comment: Thanks, just what I was looking for. Trying it out now. Would you recommend setting `xhr` back to null in my post's `always()` handler? Or would this code still work okay if the post had returned long ago?

Comment: If jQuery resolves the defered callbacks in the done or fail methods, I don't think your callback will get exected after that point. So yes, you should probably set it to null after you get the response

Comment: This is ingenious! +1 :)